# android studio keeps showing me an error "app:mergeDebugResources FAILED"

Tags: android-studio

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\this pc\AndroidStudioProjects\emptyactivity

> Configure project :app
>   useNewCruncher has been deprecated. It will be removed in a future version of the gradle plugin. New cruncher is now always enabled.
>
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860)' to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
  >   org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path 'C:\Users\this pc.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f6ed41b38e8427d403579915f9e52e7b\aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is with the gradle, so you can install a new gradle from gradle.org and change the path of the gradle in the andriod studio and it will work